# asp.net boilerplate: value cannot be null. Paramater name: key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-boilerplate

**I'm trying to create a record in db but I take this error at below.**

[image: its image of error page buy may not work]

**This is the error**

```
 ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
 Parameter name: key
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.FindEntry(TKey key)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.RequestCookieCollection.ContainsKey(string key)
Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.Antiforgery.AbpAutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter.ShouldValidate(AuthorizationFilterContext context) in AbpAutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter.cs
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

**This is my controller:**

```
  public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public  IActionResult Index(CreateUserInput input)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Request.Cookies.ContainsKey(".AspNetCore.Antiforgery."))
        {
            _userAppService.Create(input);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
    }
```

**this is my html page:**

```
  @model DutyV2.Users.DTO.CreateUserInput
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<form asp-action="Index" method="post">
    <div class="input-group">
        <label class="control-label" asp-for="Name"></label>
        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <label class="control-label" asp-for="Email"></label>
        <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" type="email" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
</form>
```

Comment: put break point and check in the controller what values you are getting in that

Comment: @Justcode break point is not working. I guess it's not reaching to controller.

Comment: If `AbpAutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter` is a class accessible to you I would suggest putting a breakpoint on the `ShouldValidate(context)` method. From the stack trace you provided I can see that inside that method a call for `RequestCookieCollection.ContainsKey(key)` is made with passed null key argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your ABP version to v4.0.1 or above.

It is due to `ContainsKey` getting called with `null` if cookie authentication is not used.

The bug occurred in `AbpAutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter` and `AbpValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter`.

The relevant pull request: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/pull/3986

Comment: Thanks, when I add Authentication problem is solved. Maybe it's not a good solution but for now its ideal.